# What do the "F+" and "F-" pins on a power supply unit stand for?

Tags: power-supply, markings

I have a power supply unit I extracted from a media player and there is a pin connector with the labels "-24V", "GND", "F+", "F-". I know what the first two mean but what do the last "F+" "F-" mean? Also bonus points if you can tell me why there is a negative 24V rail but not an opposite positive one (24V)?

[image: Picture]

Comment: A fan could be one guess.  As for why *negative* 24v, it might be helpful to figure out what was using it.  If that were something where the positive side where more easily connected to a metal mounting / heatsink bracket than the negative, it could make sense to use it with a negative supply.  Or perhaps it needs to be negative relative to other circuitry.  It's always better when you can give more context from the rest of the machine than just a connector label.  But it looks like the connector and some supporting components weren't installed on yours.

Comment: Context is GOLD here. Trying to guess from a photo of a small part  is like solving a puzzle from a single piece.  There could be many reasons. -24V could be from a vintage piece of Germanium PNP gear. +/-F could be filament.  But those are WILD guesses absent any kind of context.

Comment: Well these pins were not connected to anything, the ones that are which can be seen on the bottom right, are 5V and 12V rails. Honestly, I don't have any more context to give you I just thought they could have been some standard label that I didn't know about.

Comment: You are not showing the voltage regulators. Why? I do not have time for guessing games, as showing the entire board could make the pin functions (-24, +F, -F) more obvious. -24 could be fan power, F+/F- could be focus control. Why not just toss in the + infinity sign? No +24 volts just means it does not need a bipolar power supply for high-voltage op-amps, etc.

Comment: Could you include a picture of the bottom of the board, as well as the rest of the top? That could help figure out what those connections go to and what they do.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that the media player used a **vacuum fluorescent display** (VFD) and that the **-24 V** was required for that.

[image]

*Figure 1. Vacuum fluorescent display. Source [Wikipedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vacuum_fluorescent_1.jpg).*

---

**+5 V** is clearly for the logic.

---

**VFD filaments**

[image]

*Figure 2. VFD cross-section showing filaments. Source: [Noritake Electric](https://www.noritake-elec.com/display/vfd_operation.html).*

Thanks to @DaveTweed for suggesting "filament" for **F+ and F-**. This led me to the Noritake Itron page linked above. They state:

> The electrons emitted from the cathode filaments are controlled by the grids. When the grid is supplied with a positive voltage, it attracts the negative electrons, diffuses them and, due to their acceleration, many flow through the grid mesh towards the anode (opposite charges attract). However, when the grid is supplied with a negative voltage, it repels the negative electrons and prevents them from reaching the anode (similar charges repel).

The rest of the article is quite interesting and detailed. I was not aware of the details of operation. I think the filaments are visible as seven light horizontal lines in the photo of Figure 1.

Comment: If your guess is true, then the F terminals would be for the filament.

Comment: Thanks @Dave. That led me on some research. I learned something new today.

Comment: While this makes the most sense to me, the DVD player does not have a VFD. However I am wouldn't rule this possibility out because the pins were not connected to anything. Why would the board's designer include them? I am not sure.

Comment: Do the F+ and F- traces connect to the missing components (in photo)? I suspect a common PCB for various display options. You only told us it was a "media player" and didn't give a whole lot to go on.